# automatically change data returns from the model in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to change automatically the data returns from the model in CodeIgniter 4.
That's what comes to my mind, but it's not works:

```
class UserModel extends Model {
    protected $afterFind = ['getImage'];
        
    protected function getImage(array $data) {
            if ($data['user_image'] == 0) {
                    $data['user_image'] = "New Value";
            }
            return $data;
        
    }
}
```

Anyone have an idea how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: _Change automatically the data_ means?

Comment: Manipulate the returning data. For example: if information in a particular record is empty to change it with my value

Comment: Ok, use `if(empty($data['user_image']))`

Comment: By any chance do you mean automatically setting values to defaults from DB query? If yes, you can simply set default values in column definition itself.

Comment: I can't do it from the DB itself. Because the value is programmaticly that comes according to user preferences.
I just have to find a way, that every time I get data from db (with "find","get", functions or whatever) a function will run before/after it and will change the data.
Like the code I posted above (which unfortunately does not work)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
class UserModel extends Model {
    protected $afterFind = ['getImage'];
        
    protected function getImage(array $data) {
            if ($data['data']['user_image'] == 0) {
                    $data['data']['user_image'] = "New Value";
            }
            return $data;
        
    }
}
```